# Having problems with writing sql query on SQL Server 2008

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have this Table

```
1   a   d
1   a   e
2   b   f
2   b   g
3   c   h
3   c   i
3   c   j
3   c   k
```

and i want to this result

```
1   a   d,e
2   b   f,g
3   c   h,I,j,k,l
```

Comment: Is this supposed to look like a real question ?

Comment: what columns do you have exactly? is "1 a d,e" one column, 3 or 4 columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, SQL-Server has no built in way to do so, but you can make use of the [`FOR XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to do so:

```
SELECT 
  t1.col1,
  t1.col2,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + t2.col3
    FROM Table1 t2
    WHERE t2.col1 = t1.col1
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS Groups
FROM Table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.col1, col2;
```

This will give you:

```
| COL1 | COL2 |     GROUPS |
----------------------------
|    1 |    a |       d, e |
|    2 |    b |       f, g |
|    3 |    c | h, i, j, k |
```

[SQL Server fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1af14/3)

**However,** MySQL has a built in function, `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT
  col1, col2, GROUP_CONCAT( col3 SEPARATOR ',') groups
FROM Table1
GROUP BY col1, col2;
```

[Mysql Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24278/4)

Comment: maybe you mean `SELECT
  col1, MAX(col2), GROUP_CONCAT(col3 SEPARATOR ',') groups` ?

Comment: @JW. Sorry I missed that, the sample data wasn't formatted properly and I didn't see that, I think `SELECT col1, col2, GROUP_CONCAT of the col3 GROUP BY col1, col2` will be enough for that. Thanks.

Comment: No problem for formatted i have solve this problem with the help of your query. thanks you are great.